# How to check if a List contains empty dictionary or not

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Suppose I have these 2 dicts:

```
empty_retr = {'info': [], 'return': [{}]}
non_empty_retr = {'info': [], 'return': [{'some_host': True, 'some_more_host': True, 'Blah': True}]}
```

I want to check if the empty_retr['return'] is a list containing some dictionary with data or not. How can we do it with simplicity and maintaining pythonic way?

Comment: `empty_retr['return'] == [{}]`?

Comment: Could you provide some more context - what have you tried? What are the constraints - is `'return'`'s value always a list of one item, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if empty_retr['return']== [{}]:
   do something
```

Comment: If u do a len([{}]) it will still return 1, so I feel that this will be the most sensible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
if not empty_retr['return'][0]:
    # do something with the empty dict
```

This also works:

```
if not bool(empty_retr['return'][0]):
    # do something with the empty dict
```

Comment: `not bool(...)` seems redundant - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: the question was if it is a list containing a dictionary. this could be anything except `None` , `0`, or `False`...

Comment: @BramDekker This is not correct , Since the dictionary exist in both cases. I am curious on how to check if the dict is empty or not

Comment: @ReconAlpha my answer checks if the dict is empty. In general if you have a dict *d*, `not d` returns True if *d* is empty and False if *d* is not empty

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if its dictionary containing stuff or not, you have to check if it's a dictionary:

```
if isinstance(empty_retr['return'][0], dict):
    # do something
```

Edit:

If it should be a list containing a dictionary that should can be empty:

```
if isinstance(empty_retr['return'], list) 
        and isinstance(empty_retr['return'][0], dict):
    # do something
```